# Encrypt/Decrypt a serialized file

Tags: c#, serialization, encryption

Hey all I am trying to serialize a list of strings to a file, and then encrypt it.
Currently its just not working.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Binary stream '199' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

Then I need to decrypt and deseralize it. Heres what I have so far:

Encrypting and seralizing:

```
public  void EncryptFile(FileInfo targetFile, string password, List<string> lines)
{
    int SaltSize = 8;
    var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize);
    var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();

    // BlockSize, KeySize in bit --> divide by 8
    rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
    rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);

    using (var fileStream = targetFile.Create())
    {
        // write random salt
        fileStream.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, SaltSize);

        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            bformatter.Serialize(fileStream, lines);


        }
    }
}
```

And un-seralizing and decrypting:

```
int SaltSize = 8;


Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();



var fileStream = File.Open(SettingsFile, FileMode.Open);
var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
fileStream.Read(salt, 0, SaltSize);

// initialize algorithm with salt
var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("Y8LwUKQVJkqRz2ZAKsAMtFWY", salt);
var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);

// decrypt
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

    List<string> settingsList = (List<string>)bformatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
    foreach (string setting in settingsList)
    {
        string[] bothWords = setting.Split(',');
        settings.Add(bothWords[0], bothWords[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full exception.

Comment: I posted the full exception, thanks

Comment: is the *password* in *EncryptFile* "Y8LwUKQVJkqRz2ZAKsAMtFWY" ?

Comment: Yep it is, the issue to with the binary header, so I think by seralizing it after encrypting it causes an issue. It works fine without encrypting it...

Comment: By "full exception", I mean (for troubleshooting only), catch the exception, then post ex.ToString().

Comment: I assume your Serialize needs to write to the cryptostream, not directly to the filestream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you aren't actually encrypting your data. The way I like to picture the encryption process is imagining a `CryptoStream` as a magical "portal" that encrypts/decrypts data. In order to encrypt or decrypt, you need to push or pull data through the "portal" from one side to the other.

A simple change to your encrypting code should do the trick:

**Before**

```
using (var fileStream = targetFile.Create())
{
    // write random salt
    fileStream.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, SaltSize);

    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(fileStream, lines);


    }
}
```

**After**

```
using (var fileStream = targetFile.Create())
{
    // write random salt
    fileStream.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, SaltSize);

    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, lines); //changed the input stream to 'cryptoStream'
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(); //added a call to FlushFinalBlock
    }
}
```

You can kinda imagine the relationships here between everything. The `fileStream` is behind the `cryptoStream`. The `Serialize` method is "pushing" the data from `lines`, through the `cryptoStream` (the "portal"), and into the `fileStream`.

---

As an aside, disposing of your IDisposable objects is fairly important. Make sure to either call `Dispose()` on them or (better yet) put them into a `using` statement. The `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and `Rijndael` objects you are using aren't being disposed of.